# MVC3: How to return table structure as EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Im wanting to create an editor for a List of Models which exists as a property in my ViewModel class.

ViewModel class:

```
public class FooManagementDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<FooPermissionModel> FooPermissions { get; set; }
```

Model class:

```
public class FooPermissionModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

EditorTemplate:

```
@model FooPermissionModel
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Heading
            </th>
            <th>
                Heading
            </th>
            <th>
                Heading
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Reason)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

View:

```
   <fieldset>
      <legend>FooBarTitle</legend>
         <div>
             @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FooPermissions)
         </div>
   </fieldset>
```

What im being returned is a single div of the Names only. No structure at all. 
What am i missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see CompanyName in your model, is that a typo?

Comment: What do you have in your view?

Comment: Would it not be best to use EditorForModel? And do it based on the model. not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you may have not specified either your model name correctly or perhaps your EditorTemplate is not being found by MVC.

Note, that the template location for this example is: ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/FooPermissionModel.cshtml

The following shows the EditorTemplate rendering correctly:

Model:

```
public class FooPermissionModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class FooManagementDetailViewModel
{
    public List<FooPermissionModel> FooPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var fakePerms = new List<FooPermissionModel> () 
    { 
        new FooPermissionModel { Name = "Foo1", Reason = "Boo", Selected=true }, 
        new FooPermissionModel { Name = "Bazz", Reason = "Tootsie", Selected=false }
    };

    var model = new FooManagementDetailViewModel();
    model.FooPermissions = fakePerms;

    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model StackExamples.Models.FooManagementDetailViewModel
<fieldset>
    <legend>FooBarTitle</legend>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FooPermissions)
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

EditorTemplate:

```
@model StackExamples.Models.FooPermissionModel
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Heading
            </th>
            <th>
                Heading
            </th>
            <th>
                Heading
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Reason)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is precisely the setup I have implemented. I too have a feeling MVC isnt finding the template but it is in the location you specified. ~Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/... .cshtml Is there any way I can manually set this location? Or check it is finding the template?

Comment: There was a naming convention issue, now fixed. Such a trivial error. Sigh, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your @model should be FooManagementDetailViewModel and then you can foreach the FooPermissions.Items which will be FooPermissions objects

Comment: But the partial view editor template is for the FooPermission model. Those are the fields i wish to display. If i changed it to FooManagementDetailViewModel then I would have access to the property but not the FooPermissionModel fields? It does imply a foreach as i get a set of results back for each entry in the List<FooPermissionModel>

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see the EditorTemplate bit, I thought it was a View. My apologies.

Comment: Ah, no worries. Thought you might have been on to something then!

Comment: @MattTolliday I didn't think EditorFor works with lists, wouldn't `HTML.Partial('_yourPartial',Model.FooPermissions)` and then a foreach in your partial do the job?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `EditorForModel()`

View:

```
@model FooPermissionModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("bar", "foo"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit</legend>

        @Html.EditorForModel()

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
       </p>
     </fieldset>
 }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        //get instance of model
        // <CODE GOES HERE>


        // then pass it in the return
        return View(mymodelinstance);
    }
```

Using a correct template, it should do the rest for you and place it into a table.